# replace multiple strings in one line with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a list of packagenames and want to delete some of those with `sed`

```
echo "package1 package2 package24 package44 package66 package12345" > benoetigte_pakete.list
```

How can I delete some of those that are in another list?

```
dellist="package24|package66"
```

I tried

```
cat benoetigte_pakete.list | sed "s/(package24|package66)//"
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `sed` regexps you have to escape `(`, `|`, and `)`.

You also need to use the `g` modifier so it replaces all matches on the line, not just the first match.

```
dellist="package24|package66"
# escape the pipes
dellist=${dellist//|/\\|}
sed "s/\b\($dellist\)\b//g" benoietigte_packete.list
```

I've added the `\b` so it only matches whole words.

Depending on the version of `sed` you have, you can also use the `-E` or `-r` options to use extended regular expressions.

Comment: Is there a way to add those `\\` automatically before the pipe?

Comment: You can use string substitution to add the backslashes, see my update

Comment: Why not just use `-r` or `-E`? `|` doesn't need to be escaped in extended regex syntax.

Comment: I used `-r` without pipe escapation now (debian wheezy). Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to add some parentheses and anchors or that would change `package246` to `6`, etc.

Comment: I guess that would be `dellist=${dellist//|/\\b\\|}`